# error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] when trying building the project

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I have a service class and I want to provide it via Dagger. But I get this error below:

> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] service.KeyStoreService cannot be
>   provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated
>   method. service.KeyStoreService is provided at
>   di.component.ApplicationComponent.getKeyStoreService()

Here is my component class:

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = {ApplicationContextModule.class, KeyStoreModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    @ApplicationContext
    Context getApplicationContext();

    KeyStoreService getKeyStoreService();

}
```

Here is my KeyStoreModule:

```
@Module(includes = {ApplicationContextModule.class})
public class KeyStoreModule {

    @Provides
    @ApplicationScope
    KeyStoreServiceInterface getKeyStoreService(@ApplicationScope Context context){
        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "keystore/keystore");
        return new KeyStoreService(file);
    }
}
```

KeyStoreService implements KeyStoreServiceInterface.

Here is how I start Dagger2:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationContextModule(new ApplicationContextModule(this))
                .build();

    }

}
```

Anyone see where it could have gone wrong? I looked at similar questions on Stackoverflow but did not find anything that helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a thing: Dagger provides instances based on **specific type**. Here are a couple of ways to deal with this problem

- Change the return type of `getKeyStoreService` method from `KeyStoreServiceInterface` to `KeyStoreService` in `KeyStoreModule`
- Change the return type of `getKeyStoreService` method from `KeyStoreService` to `KeyStoreServiceInterface` in `ApplicationComponent`
- Create an abstract method with `@Binds` annotation which will receive `KeyStoreService` and which return type will be `KeyStoreServiceInterface` (in order to do this the whole module should be abstract - so it is possible to either create separate abstract module with `@Binds` annotations or to make `KeyStoreModule` abstract and modify `getKeyStoreService` method to be static)
- Again, using `@Binds` annotation to map `KeyStoreService` instance to the provided `KeyStoreServiceInterface`, but applying `@Inject` annotation on `KeyStoreService` constructor and provide keystore `File` through Dagger
- Not using `@Binds` annotation, but applying `@Inject` annotation on `KeyStoreService` constructor and provide keystore `File` through Dagger